# How should I save an element in CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I want to save an element in a variable.

This is my code

```
var casper = require("casper").create();
var data = "";

casper.start("http://www.naver.com",function(){
      data = require('utils').dump(this.getElementsAttribute("#name","cy"));
});

casper.run();
```

This doesn't work!

If I remove (data =) part, then it makes a log in cmd...

But, I didn't even used this.echo !!

Selector `#name` doesn't actually exists in www.naver.com

It is too long, so I just used `#name` for a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some basic idea about `CasperJS`... I write a small sample code for you to illustrate extracting data by css selector:

```
var casper = require("casper").create();
var data;

casper.start("http://stackoverflow.com/users/6571228/cute-developer",function() {
    data = casper.evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('#user-card > div > div.row.col-content > div.col-left.col-8.about > div.bio > p').textContent;
    })
}).then(function () {
    casper.echo("result:\n" + data);
});

casper.run();
```

Output:

```
$ casperjs evaluate2.js 
result:
I wanna be a best Korean woman developer.
```

Feel free to leave a comment here if you still got some questions about `CasperJS`...